# How to test the status of a an object at a specific state?

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I have a ReportHandler class, which can produce a report with 3 different statuses.

- InProgress, when the report is being generated (this could take from seconds to minutes)
- Success, when everything is OK
- Error, when something has gone wrong

Inside the handler class, there is a mocked report generator, which setting it up accordingly, to return a report or throw an exception, I can test those scenarios.

My problem is, that I need to write a test for the report which is in 'InProgress' status.

```
public async Task WriteReportAsync(SearchTermsRequestData requestData, string correlationId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        WriteToFile(new Report { Status = ReportStatusType.InProgress.ToString() }, correlationId, _applicationSettings.OutputPath);
        var reportGenerator = _reportGeneratorFactory.GetReportGenerator(requestData);

        try
        {
            // reportGenerator is mocked in tests
            // once is mocked to return a report = success
            // once is mocked to throw exeption = error
            var report = await reportGenerator
                .Generate(requestData);
            report.Status = ReportStatusType.Success.ToString();
            WriteToFile(report, correlationId, _applicationSettings.OutputPath);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            WriteToFile(new Report { Status = ReportStatusType.Error.ToString(), Error = exception.Message }
                , correlationId, _applicationSettings.OutputPath);
            _logger.Error(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

How could i write a test, which can check the InProgress status which the report is written with as soon as the WriteReportAsync method is called?

I have thought to write a moq with delay, but that delays the the overall execution and the assertions arent hit until the delay has passed, so that doesnt work.

Comment: Why that test would be needed at all cause your end status will either be Success or Error

Comment: @Rahul Am pedantic and want that part covered too, yes I manually tested with a breakpoint, but want to have it covered in my tests and want to see a green tick next to it.

Comment: You shouldn't test for this. As far as asynchronous semantics go, it would be perfectly legal for an implementation to instantaneously produce `Success` as a synchronous operation. The only relevant test here would be that the status is *not* `InProgress` when the method completes. No correctly written code could depend on `InProgress` appearing "somewhere in between" without itself being the victim of a race condition. You'd need a method/event handler for reporting progress in the generator itself to have an observable point in time where such a test would not be meaningless.